# How to check captcha before symofny login

Tags: php, symfony

Now, I just add a `security.interactive` Event Listener to check captcha. But it is used to check after login check. I think it will need too many username&password validations.

So, I want to validate the captcha before login.

**UPDATE:**
Now, I am using [`simple_form`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html) to replace `form_login` in `security.yml`.
I add the captcha validation in function `createToken`.
It has been logged in but not be authenticated. I cannot access the `access_control` space. 
[image]
I don't which the right way is.

Comment: If you want help it woud be usefull to provide at least the code you want to modify.

Comment: Thx for your comment. I think it isn't the code problem. It is a usage problem. I don't know how to check captcha before security login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `security.interactive_login` is triggered by Symfony once the user has logged in. In fact, it is how Symfony says "hey, I just logged in someone!". What you need to do is to create an event listener that is called before the security component is called, maybe by listening to the `kernel.request` event

Comment: Thx for your answer. Having add the listener to `kernel.request`, it will trigger every request. I just want it trigger in login event.

Comment: Well, you cannot use the `interactive_login`event because it is raised after the user is logged in, and there is no event which is raised before the user is logged in. You will probably have to look at creating your custom authentication provider: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html